# Ls after cat does not work in Linux

Tags: linux, cat, ls, xargs

I have a file, containing filepaths, so when I try to list all the path with the following command:

```
cat whitelist.txt | xargs ls
```

it displays: No such file or directory.

whitelist.txt contains valid file paths like:
`../work/DRA.I3OKGZ.G0200.IB*` `../work/DFL.KA6KGZ.G0320.IB*`
....

`ls` works and there are such kinds of files. 
So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

* does not get expanded.

If you want to keep the "cat | xargs" style, you could do something like

```
cat whitelist.txt | xargs -I@ sh -c "ls @"
```

Comment: I don`t have permission to execute sh -c, only sh